# SCIP emit pre-solved output to file

Tags: preprocessor, scip

Is it possible to emit SCIP pre-solved output to a .lp or .mps file?  I am interested in using the presolver to generate a simplified MIP problem instance.  This would allow me to test an alternate solver against some of the ones in SCIP such that I get an 'apples-to-apples' comparison.

Answer (score 1):

As you said it is possible to do this. If you are running SCIP through the interactive shell, simply use the `presolve` command.

Afterwards you can write out the pre-solved problem using `write transproblem <yourfilename>`.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorials did not cover it, but it appears that there is a 'presolve' command that can be used to simplify a problem instance without running the solver.  I will try this and determine whether it meets my use case.